# Information and Videos for Customers in the Backend

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, profiles

I am looking for ideas or plugins that would allow me to have a backend area for clients to log into my site and access files specifically assigned to them. I provide video IT help files for clients which contain information specific to their setup and would also like to have the ability to offer or accept files from them through this backend (files that would never make it through email). Does such a backend plugin exist?

Thanks in advance stack!

Comment: You should use the normal "help" tab in admin UI screens.

Comment: Why not use a password protected post or page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Justin Tadlock's members plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). You can then create custom roles per user in the *Users/Roles/Add New* section of the WP-Admin Area. Once the role is created, you can add custom capabilities. I've never tried the email option you've mentioned, but it's possible. If you go this route I'll try to help you figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, I think I can work with this plugin. Thanks for the reply!